# Pass props to other component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have following structure of my `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
      <Header />    
      <App />
      <Footer />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And my `App.js` looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    // ... etc
                </React.Fragment>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is **I want to differently render my `Footer` based on what component is displayed in `App` component**. That is I want to add some additional stuff to my `Footer` if `Main` component is rendered, for any other component footer isn't changed. Is there any way to do that? I want to pass a prop and render footer based on it, but how do I pass it through such structure? Maybe I need to reorganize my code to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: What you want is for separate components to have access to the same piece(s) of data. Check out react's [new context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) - it's exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @Adam seems it really is, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the same property to `Footer` and `App` from your parent component.
For this reason, it is better to wrap these two in another component.

Example:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>HEADER</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>APP: {this.props.name}</div>
  }
}

class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.color === 'test' ? <div>FOOTER TEST</div> : <div>FOOTER NOT TEST</div>;
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
        <Header />    
        <App {...this.props} />
        <Footer {...this.props} />
      </React.Fragment>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main name="test"></Main>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `<Footer />` element inside of the "routes-provider" you may access the current route out of the Footer and afterwards you can define your definitions.

Something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let path = this.props.location.pathname
  this.setState({path})
}

render() {
  if (this.state.path === '/main') {
    return <div>main</div>
  } else {
    return <div>not main</div>
  }
}
```

Another possibility would be to wrap your app and the footer into a "higher order component" and pass the relevant props to them.